# Working with both http and https

Tags: .htaccess

I don't know much about working with .htaccess files. I've tried researching. So, maybe someone could help me out on here. I want to allow https and http at the same time. Let me explain.

http is working but a website on **HTTPS** is giving me a error in the console

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://domain1.com/data.json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.domain1.coms' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://www.domain1.com' is therefore not allowed access.*

If I change the "http" to "**https**" it works for the https website but then the http website doesn't work.  How do I allow both at the same time?

I hope that made any sense to you guys! Thank you for any help!

**Here is my code:**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain.com|domain2.com|domain3.com|domain4.com|domain5.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I hope I've understood this correctly, but if you're happy for users to access your website through `http` or `https` then you don't actually need to do anything in your `.htaccess`. Generally, you use `.htaccess` to force one or the other, or for specific pages etc. Like wp-admin for example. The user will be able to type either `http` or `https` and the secure version will work if they wish to use it.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another answer has pointed out, the `$1` should be removed as it is the `s` from `https://` being appended to the end of the URL, so it should be changed to:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain.com|domain2.com|domain3.com|domain4.com|domain5.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
```

This will make sure `AccessControlAllowOrigin` is set to the exact value of the `Origin` header.

I think the reason for `http://` to work sometimes and `https://` sometimes is because the browser most likely caches the response from the server.  So you should either respond with both `http://` and `https://`, or you should specify the `Vary: Origin` header to inform the browser that the response depends on the `Origin` header.

I would also suggest changing `Header add` to `Header set`, `Header merge` or `Header append`, since the `mod_headers` documentation states:

```
add
The response header is added to the existing set of headers, even
if this header already exists. This can result in two (or more)
headers having the same name. This can lead to unforeseen
consequences, and in general set, append or merge should be used
instead.
```

So, my suggestion is to specify the Vary header:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain.com|domain2.com|domain3.com|domain4.com|domain5.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
    Header merge Vary Origin
</IfModule>
```

Or specify both `http://` and `https://`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "https?://(www\.)?(domain.com|domain2.com|domain3.com|domain4.com|domain5.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$1$2
    Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://%{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://%{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
    Header merge Vary Origin
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer seems to provide some [useful information on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/7236046). However, it looks like you may be trying to load the content from a different website due to a typo.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://domain1.com/data.json. The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   ***'https://www.domain1.coms'*** that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'https://www.domain1.com' is therefore not allowed access.

The TLD is `.coms`, make sure it's requesting the resource from the right place, so from `.com` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are ways first is by creating virtual host. To do this neeed to make change http conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 'http://www.domain1.com'
DocumentRoot /var/www/your-domain-root
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/your-domain-root
ServerName 'https://www.domain1.com'
SSLEngine On
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key
SSLProtocol TLSv1
</VirtualHost>
```

Secondly, we can do this using htaccess. In htaccess we can use 301 redirects. Website in ssl(http://) will be our base website and non ssl(http://) website will be secondary. Redirect all requests from http:// to https://. For redirecting you can use 301 redirects or mod_rewrite any.

Let me know if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[I am replying here because I can't reply to @Daniel James's answer.]

I have the same situation as OP's. The 's' at the end of 'com' is not a typo.
If I change the rule to:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain.com|domain2.com|domain3.com|domain4.com|domain5.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
```

which is without the $1 at the end, it works fine with requests from **https** pages, but it blocks the ones from **http**.

If I leave the $1, the **http** ones work, but not the **https**.

[Later edit]

I am awarding the bounty to Victor Jerlin, as his first suggestion worked for me. Thank you so much!